# jQuery collapse bootsstrap and jQuery slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with 4 rows and 2 cols, in each of this rows is a bootstrap accordion and an image which is in the other column. When the header is clicked the accordion opens(bootstrap collapse) and a hidden div with images is shown under the image already visible (slide jQuery).

So with one click 2 divs open(accordion body+hidden div), this works for all 4 accordions when I use different ids for the accordions, but they stay open.

When I use the same id for the accordions for closing the accordion body I have problems.

The jquery slide needs probably a noConflict and a click function(the onClick isn't the way to go I read somewhere) and another else statement.

What I want is that it doesn't matter which header you click, only the clicked accordion opens + hidden div with images shown.

Is there anybody out there.....who can help.

```
function slide(slides) {
 $('.slidepic').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == slides) {
           $(this).slideDown(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).slideUp(200);
      }
 });
}
```

A 2 row version of the page is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SUpmn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SUpmn/4/

Means, got the click with the jquery click-Event-Handler. Don't use javascript: uglyFunction()

```
$('.accordion-heading').click(function (){
$('.slidepic').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == slides) {
        $(this).slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $(this).slideUp(200);
    }
});
});
}
```

Comment: it solves my uglyFuntion()Thanks,but not my problem to combine the slide function with the bootstrap collapse. I've found no solution for this so far and since I'm not coding JQuery I need the experts to help me out.

Comment: This script might combine them, but it doesn't work. Even when I took out the onClick which was still in the fiddle.